# Saving values to database - logic error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

in the following example when we click the button, all the form data (both the `KEY-VALUE`) will be passed to the php file to be saved in the database. Grabbing the `KEY-VALUE` is done by `var form = this.up('form').getForm();` statement.

**UPDATE 3**

```
Ext.define ('Mycomp.model.MyClass',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields:['textfieldone']

});
```

========================================================================

**UPDATE 2**

When a user clicks on a button, i display the View that has one textfield and a button (as shown in the following code). The user will enter some values and click on the button, and the value entered by the user in the text field should be saved in the DB (The `Store` has the link to the path of the PHP code)

CONTROLLER

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.controller.MyClass',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores:['MyClass'],
    models:['MyClass'],
    views:['MyClassView'],
    init: function(){
        this.control({          
            'myclassview button[action=save]': {
                click: this.myMethod
            }
        });         
        },
        myMethod: function(button,record) {
               var win    = button.up('window'),
               form   = win.down('form'),
               record = form.getForm().getRecord(),
               values = form.getForm().getValues();
               console.log (values);
               console.log (record);
               record.getRecord().set(values);         
           win.close();
           this.this.getMyClassStore().sync(); 
    }
});
```

VIEW

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.view.user.MyClassView', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.myclassview',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'textfieldone',
                        fieldLabel: 'Contact Person Name'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        this.buttons = [
                        {
                            text: 'Save',
                            name:'save',
                            action: 'save'
                        }
                    ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

STORE

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.store.Myclass',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'App.model.Myclass',

    proxy: {
        actionMethods : {
            create : 'POST'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/savetodb.php'

    }

});
```

===============================================================================

**UPDATE 1**

```
 ....  this.buttons = [
                            {
                                text: 'Save',

                                action: 'save'
                            }, ...
```

STORE

```
Ext.define('Mycomp.store.Myclass',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'App.model.Myclass',

    proxy: {
        actionMethods : {
            create : 'POST'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/savetodb.php'

    }

});
```

CONTAROLLER

```
this.control({

            'mycalssform button[action=save]': {
                click: this.myMethod
            }
        });


        },

        myMethod: function(button, record) {

               var win    = button.up('window'),
               form   = win.down('form'),
               record = form.getRecord(),
               values = form.getValues();
               console.log (record);
      console.log (values );

           record.set(values);
           win.close();
           this.this.getmyClassStore().sync();
```

FIREBUG OUT PUT >> It says RECORD IS UNDEFINED . Why is this ?

```
undefined

Object { textfileldone="hello", textfileldtwo="bever", more...}

record is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

record.set(values);
```

Comment: Why is this down voted, even without a comment

Comment: is `textfieldone` part of your model?

Comment: `textfieldone` is part of Model, and also in the MySQL db i have named a column as `textfieldone`, and also in the View i have a textfield with the name `textfieldone`.

Comment: Could you post the request (shown in firebug or chrome developer tools)?

Comment: I have updated my question, and i have added my latest code, and now i get an error saying `Record is undefined`. Can you please help me here ?

Comment: When i print the `record` it says `undefined` in firebug. but when i print `value` i get some values in firebug

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `form.getForm().getRecord()` and `form.getForm().getValues()`

Comment: Do you mean to replace `record = form.getRecord()` with `record = form.getForm().getRecord()` and `values = form.getValues()` with `values = form.getForm().getValues()` ?? Still it doesn't work, i get the same message `form.getForm() is undefined`

Comment: I see. Your issue seem to be very basic. Could you post the full code of your controller; the code of your view; and how and where you load a record onto the form?

Comment: See **UPDATE 2** i have included the files.

Comment: OK, why would the form have a record? Have you created a new model record anywhere and called `form.loadRecord()`?

Comment: No i haven't have anything called `form.loadRecord()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the form to be 'bound' to a record you'd need to create a new model instance and call `form.loadRecord()` - only after doing so you'll `form.getRecord()` will work.

Alternatively (which would be suitable if you only use to form with new records), you can simply create a new model record upon save and set its values.

Something along these lines will create a new model record:

```
var iStore = this.getmyClassStore();
var iModel = iStore.model; 
var iNewRecord = iModel.create();
```

You can then perform:

```
iValues = form.getValues();
iNewRecord.set( iValues );
```

And then you'll need to add the new record to the store:

```
iStore.add( iNewRecord )
```

So your code should look like this:

```
    myMethod: function(button, record) {

           var win    = button.up('window'),
               form   = win.down('form'), 
               values = form.getValues(),
               store = this.this.getmyClassStore(),
               model = store.model,
               record = model.create();


               record.set( values );
               store.add( record );
               win.close();
               store.sync(); 
    }
```

Comment: Well, i already have defined a Model. And i have included it above (under update 3). Do you want me to add those 3 lines of code to that Model class ?

Comment: All I'm saying is that your form is not referencing a model record. Somewhere in your code you need to create the right model record (the model of the store) and then set the values you get from the form. Would you be able to work this out or do you need me to copy/paste/change the code you have posted?

Comment: Please, could you kindly copy paste the code. I am a bit stuck with this all day

Comment: Yes, i got rid of that error. but the record that i am passing is not getting displayed when i echo $_POST[textfieldone];

Comment: Would help to see the definition of your model. Also, the request debug of firebug/chrome developer tools...

Comment: There's no such error message, the PHP file gets executed, and all string echo statements gets printed, except for `echo $_POST['textfieldone'];`

Comment: How do I do a put instead of a post in this?